# Network Load Balancing Windows server 2008

Tags: load-balancing, nlb, windows-nlb

I have a questions about load balancing configurations. Maybe someone already asked this question but I didn't find something similar on the web.

The Actual Configuration is .

I Have two servers that I want to load balance.

Server 1 has two NIC

```
NIC 1 IP :xx.xx.xx.35 Gateway : xx.xx.xx.33
NIC 2 IP 192.168.2.11
```

Server 2

```
NIC 1 IP :xx.xx.yy.45 Gateway : xx.xx.yy.43
NIC 2 IP 192.168.2.10
```

So server 1 and 2 are connected with the second NIC

I Want to load balance those two server using the NIC 2  But all the traffic coming from NIC1 should be reparted between the two servers.

And until now and didn't find any way to do it . I can't really find information if it's possible or not.

Comment: The reason you haven't found any resources on this is because it doesn't really make any sense. What's the actual problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: The Actual Problem i'am triying to solve is my domain website is www.mydomain.com and it is pointing to server1 xx.xx.xx.35 so when i load balance using the second NIC  if Server1 fails the load balancer will not redirect the traffic to server 2 i think because the NIC 1 on server1 and NIC2 on server 2 are not on the samesubnet so i cannot add those ips to my cluster ! i hope that it's pretty clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oki After few months i can see that in this post we didn't get any answers.

First the two server needs to be on the same gateway or this won't work at all .
Then I found an article which says this :

"The above ARP Request Packet indicates that the Sender’s IP Address is Unicast and Sender's MAC Address is Multicast. Most routers do not respond to ARP Requests with Unicast Sender IP and Multicast Sender MAC (Multicast Cluster MAC). So, the NLB node does not get a response to the ARP request and the ping from the NLB Virtual IP Address fails as the NLB node fails to resolve the MAC address of the Gateway."

so to make it work i just run this command on my servers :

arp -s xx.xx.xx.xx 00-00-00-00-00-ff where xx.xx.xx.xx is your default gateway ip and mac adresse 00-00-00-00-00-ff

here is the complete article

http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2009/01/15/unable-to-connect-to-windows-server-2008-nlb-virtual-ip-address-from-hosts-in-different-subnets-when-nlb-is-in-multicast-mode.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a server cluster, as long as what you're serving is cluster-er-er-able.

2) If you really really want the traffic to two different nodes, look into port mirroring aka port spans (port spanning *is* possible over many switches in cisco world).

Comment: i'am going to check the port span option to see what's the purpose of it